# Using cURL to switch the user agent more than once in multiple requests

Tags: php, curl

So I'm using cURL to log into a website here, and spoofing the user agent.  I have two constants: one called `IOS` that is an iOS user agent, and one called `CHROME` that is a Chrome user agent.  Here is the code to log in:

```
    public function signIn($username, $password)
    {
        $url = "https://www.site.net/post/Index.page"; 
        $cookie = "cookie.txt"; 

        $postdata = "screenName=$username&kclq=$password&submitEvent=1&TCNK=authenticationEntryComponent&enterClicked=true&ajaxSupported=yes"; 

        $ch = curl_init(); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, IOS); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 200); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "https://www.site.net/Index.page"); 

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
        $result = curl_exec($ch); 

        curl_close($ch);
    }
```

In subsequent requests, I would like to change the user agent from `IOS` to `CHROME`, and it doesn't seem to work (I change to `CHROME` and the website still serves up a mobile page).  When I run this request:

`curl -L -X POST -b "cookie.txt" --user-agent " . CHROME . " https://site.net`

It does not serve up a desktop site, but a mobile one.  Is it possible to change the user agent while logged in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server is detecting your visit based on cookie also. So at the first line inside the function `signIn()` either empty the cookie file, or delete it.

For example:

```
file_put_contents($cookie, "");
```

or delete it, curl will create a new one:

```
unlink($cookie);
```

Answer (score 0):

The website seems to be saving the user agent as a global session variable upon logging in.  In that case, no, changing the user agent in a later curl request will not change the user agent in the session variable.